# Problem solving inequality containing absolute value

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

I need help proving this inequality. I managed to go through some steps but I'm not sure if and how I can continue with my way:

What needs to be proved:

$$(|a+b|)/(1+|a+b|)≤(|a|)/(1+|a|)+|b|/(1+|b|)$$

Here is my progress:
    $$(|a|)/(1+|a|)+(|b|)/(1+|b|)\ge \\
(|a|)/(1+|a|+|b|)+(|b|)/(1+|a|+|b|)= \\
(|a|+ |b|)/(1+|a|+ |b| )\ge \\
(|a+b|)/(1+|a|+ |b|)$$

What I still need to prove but can't manage:

$$ (|a+b|)/(1+|a|+ |b|)≥(|a+b|)/(1+|a+b|)$$

Can it be done this way or should I try a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $x\in [0,\infty)\mapsto \frac{x}{1+x}$ (by calculating its derivative or by observing what Bernard pointed out). So as $|a+b|\le |a|+|b|$, we have:

$$\frac{|a+b|}{1+|a+b|} \le \frac{|a|+|b|}{1+|a|+|b|} \\ = \frac{|a|}{1+|a|+|b|}+\frac{|b|}{1+|a|+|b|} \le \frac{|a|}{1+|a|}+\frac{|b|}{1+|b|}$$

Comment: You don't need derivatives to find it's increasing: it can be written as  $\;1-\dfrac1{1+x}$.

Comment: I now looked at this again, and don't understand the first step - how could you be sure that the second expression is smaller than the first? the denominator in the second expression is bigger than the denominator in the first expression therefore it could be smaller can't it?

Comment: @S.Peter a function is increasing if for any $x$ and $y$ such that $x\le y$, we have $f(x)\le f(y)$. Take now $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x}$. This function is increasing and $|a+b|\le |a|+|b|$, so $f(|a+b|)\le f(|a|+|b|)$. Is it clear now?